# Correlation Matrix between Text columns

Tags: r, text, correlation

I have a sample df like below.

dt <- data.frame(City = c("NewYork", "London", "Perth", "Wellington"),
Address = c("ABD", "BCA", "ACB", "ATS"))

Is there a way to get the correlation matrix for 2 text columns in R or Python?

Just to elaborate,
I have few issues and resolutions tagged to them. What i want to find out is the grouping of issue and resolutions together.

Comment: No, unless you are prepared to assign numeric values to each label, e.g. "New York" = 7 (the number of letters) and "ABD" = 8 (the sum of the letter positions 1 + 2 + 4).

Comment: While I haven't heard of ways to do this, it's certainly feasible (given @dcarlson's comment) to come up with some reproducible and robust method. (I'm not comfortable/proficient with NLP, perhaps there's a connection.) If there is a sound way to do this, then this is likely more appropriate on [stats.se] or perhaps [datascience.se].

Comment: Sample case I'm trying to solve is, There are some questions and answers to them.
I would like to understand what key themes matching between questions and answeres.

Comment: You might look into text mining applications. Another possibility would be canonical correspondence analysis in ecology where the analysis compares the presence of species to characteristics of the environment. [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to post this.